# Wordpress - get_current_user_id returns 0, but the user can only use the page (that uses that function) once logged in

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a page that uses the function get_current_user_id.  That page is only accessible once a user has logged in, however, with monolog I have logged users that return a get_current_user_id of 0.  Shouldn't the user id return non-zero if a user is already authenticated and logged in?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The user id should return non zero if a user is already logged in [unless you have a user with ID#0].

Comment: how come those pages returned a zero value?

Comment: You'll have to provide more information. What do you mean by "with monolog I have logged users that return a get_current_user_id of 0."?

Comment: well when a person accesses the page that contains the get_current_user_id call, I log the return value of that function using monolog.  the log file says that it returns the value 0 but the user can only access that page (the page that contains the get_current_user_id) if they are logged in.